# Execute JAR file using PHP

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, automation, php-webdriver

How do I execute selenium jar file and chrome driver exe

I am running below code through cmd.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=PATH/chromedriver.exe
```

How do I execute this through php code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's `exec()` function

```
$command = 'java -jar path/to/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path/to/chromedriver.exe';
exec($command);
```

Comment: Despite my earlier requests, it seems you still haven't figured out how to close duplicate questions. When you answer duplicate questions, you are not helping Stack Overflow. [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)